# Python. удалить словарь из первого списка ,если его нет во втором, по значению ключа

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1= [{'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}, {'name': 'c'}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}]

for l1 in list1:
    if l1['name'] есть ли в list2 == False:        
       print(str(l1['name']) +' удален')
```

кто что посоветует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1= [{'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}, {'name': 'c'}]
list2 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}]

list2_set = set([itemgetter('name')(c) for c in list2])
list = [c for c in list1 if c['name'] not in list2_set]
for l in list :
    print(l['name'] + 'удален')
```

спасибо MaxU ,  подтолкнул

```
vals = [x['name'] for x in list2]
for i in list1:
    if i['name'] not in vals:
        print(i['name'] + 'удален')
```

спасибо Alban, этим путем дольше на 80%

Comment: Все таки явное лучше неявного, мой ответ намного читабельнее :)

Comment: 1 месяц изучаю ,согласен про читабельность ,  но тут  данные большие  15 тыс словарей .  это лишь один из потоков ,у меня их три .    благодаря Вашим ответам , понемногу приходит понимание. спасибо

Comment: @user284883, вы можете указать в вопросе что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: MaxU  спасибо, написал уже , очень помогли

Answer (score 1):

```
In [48]: list1= [{'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}, {'name': 'c'}]
    ...: list2 = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}]
    ...:

In [53]: for i in list1:
    ...:     for j in list2:
    ...:         if i['name'] in j.values():
    ...:             print(f'Значения из {i} есть в {j}')
    ...:
Значения из {'name': 'a'} есть в {'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}
Значения из {'name': 'b'} есть в {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}
```

**UPD:**

```
In [75]: vals = [x['name'] for x in list2]

In [76]: for i in list1:
    ...:     if i['name'] not in vals:
    ...:         list1.remove(i)
    ...:

In [77]: list1
Out[77]: [{'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}]
```

Comment: тут же получается , сколько у меня словарей , столько раз он пытается у меня удалить

Comment: @user284883 можно после `print()` поставить `break`

Comment: @user284883 отредактировал ответ согласно изменениям вопроса

Comment: list1.remove(i)  не работает в этом случае

Comment: @user284883 почему?

Comment: сори, уже голова кругом , перепутал с list2

Answer (score 1):

С использованием [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
In [275]: import pandas as pd

In [276]: d1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list1)

In [277]: d2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list2)

In [278]: d1
Out[278]:
  name
0    a
1    b
2    c

In [279]: d2
Out[279]:
   id name
0   1    a
1   2    b

In [280]: pd.merge(d1, d2, on='name', how='outer', indicator=True)
Out[280]:
  name   id     _merge
0    a  1.0       both
1    b  2.0       both
2    c  NaN  left_only
```

вот еще несколько вариантов:

```
In [299]: from operator import itemgetter

In [300]: set1 = set([itemgetter('name')(c) for c in list1])

In [301]: set1
Out[301]: {'a', 'b', 'c'}

In [302]: [c for c in list2 if c['name'] in set1]
Out[302]: [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}]

In [303]: set([itemgetter('name')(c) for c in list1]) - set([itemgetter('name')(c) for c in list2])
Out[303]: {'c'}
```

Comment: In [302]: [c for c in list2 if c['name'] in set1]
Out[302]: [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}]   , только тут ссылки остаются